# Using GreedyConstructorQuery and AutoMoqCustomization does use greediest constructor and inject dependency

Tags: c#, moq, autofixture

I´m using Autofixture with Moq to inject Moq to my suts.

I have the following class with the constructors:

```
public class Dummy{

  public Dummy(){

  }

  public Dummy(IDummyData data){

  }
}
```

and i have configured the Fixture in my xUnit test using `AutoMoqCustomization` and `GreedyConstructorQuery` as follows.

```
[Fact]
public void ValidLoginShouldReturnAToken()
{
  var fixture = new Fixture()
                             .Customize(new ConstructorCustomization(typeof(Dummy), new GreedyConstructorQuery()))
                             .Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

  Dummy sut = fixture.Build<Dummy>().Create();

}
```

The problem is now that the instance of Dummy is created by using the default constructor. I expected that the instance gets created by the constructor with the most parameters and that AutoMoq will create a Mock for the interface `IDummyData` that gets injected into my sut.

So is my setup incorrect? Is my expectation wrong that? Do I need to create a Mock first and register it at my Fixture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is RTFM.

Using `Build<T>().Create()` turns of all customizations. The Solution is to use `Create<T>()` directly on the fixture to create the instance of `Dummy`.

```
[Fact]
public void ValidLoginShouldReturnAToken()
{
  var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new ConstructorCustomization(typeof(Dummy),
                                        new GreedyConstructorQuery()))
                             .Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

  Dummy sut = fixture.Create<Dummy>();

}
```

Comment: +1 Yes, in this scenario, that is the correct way to customize the `Fixture` instance. (FWIW, instead of using the `Customize` method twice, you can also use a [`CompositeCustomization`](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/CompositeCustomization.cs).)